# Circa 1980's prehistoric intelligent reptiles starving and time traveling and terraforming present day Earth for survival

Tags: story-identification, novel, terraforming

I've asked for help on identifying this novel about a year ago but nothing.  So here goes again.

Ancient intelligent lizard species running out of food to the extent they are eating their own eggs.  They invent time travel to the present and commence changing the present environment for their own purposes.  They are so superior to humans they appear as ancient "lords" or "princes" and they have vast powers. I read this in the early 90's but it may have even then been up to a decade old.

If I recall correctly, the terraforming is along the lines of the strange growths and the reptiles are long the same lines as well - in Dean Koontz' "The Taking".  The revelation about the provenance of the lizards comes quite late in the novel. Aldiss' "The Saliva Tree" is also similar but there was less skill in the book I'm after as I recall than Aldiss, who of course was simply a master.  It was nonetheless an excellent read if my aging synapses recount accurately.

Comment: Hi there! First of all - did you ask here, on this site? If so, please edit the previous question; if you posted it from a different account, please follow [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge the two. If you asked somewhere else, no probs, but it'd still be cool if you could provide a link :D

Comment: Back to the story-ID: that's some info already; could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I deleted the earlier question or at least attempted to - sorry about that.  No links and Google is useless with most of the intuitive terms - "prehistoric intelligent reptiles" draws a blank in context with Google, surprisingly.  This is becoming somewhat of an obsession unfortunately.  Cheers.

Comment: Could this be (maybe!) Time Dragon by George Gentle? I remember there were dinosaurs from the past trying to conquer and change the modern world

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, however I just googled "Time dragon" and "George Gentle" with no results.  Do you have a link to this work so I can check the synopsis and see if it accords with what I remember?

Comment: Now I'm really intrigued.  Worldcat.org has only 8 titles enumerated by strict search "Time Dragon" and the only George Gentle is a highly specialised technical author in quantum dynamics or somesuch.  Could you clarify please, the sprig of hope trembles before my eyes but on my hands are mittens!

Comment: Ah, GARY Gentle - that's why I couldn't find any reference (I was looking for George...).  An answer yes, but not the solution.  The book I'm after was not part of a series, it was standalone.  The reptiles were demonic in nature, similar to Koontz's in The Taking.  The entire premise was less frivolous than "lizards with machine guns" :)  Someday, I'll find it, one way or the other.  Thanks anyhow for bothering.

Answer (score 8):

This looks like it could be one of the books from the "Time For Dragons" Trilogy.

**NB** I haven't read it personally.

Information on these books on the internet is pretty scarce, but I found this review for the second book in the trilogy, "Dragons Past":

> This book takes place after the crew of main characters (humans) have destroyed the dragons in the present, they've struck a great blow against their enemy in the past and are headed to the Jurassic period to finish the job.

So there definitely appears to be a time travel aspect to the series.

Hopefully the cover of the first book "A Time For Dragons" will enable the QA to tell if this is the correct answer.

[image]

If this is the correct answer, then I need to give a big shout out to danny3414, whose comment above helped me find this series.

Comment: I'm a simple person. I see a dinosaur with a submachine/blaster gun, I upvote.

Comment: I'm posting a comment here that was erroneously put as an answer by the actual author  Gary Gentile, I genuinely think it's important enough to warrant inclusion in this thread:-.

I suppose that my input is quite out of date, but I only just learned about this website accidentally. Of all my books (69 and still going), the Time Dragon Series is my favorite, with "The Peking Papers" close behind. The original books are out of print and difficult to find, I suspect because buyers have held on to them for sentimental reasons.. .

Comment: @DannyMcG - Any reason you didn't post the rest of the comment?

Comment: @Hypnosifi yeah, it said I had 148 characters too many to post as a comment!